# Hover in CSS is not working with Electron

Tags: css, hover, electron

I'm starting to make my simple code editor. The window that I create with Electron is without frame (`frame: false`). Because of that, I created a div with class `.drag`, which has `-webkit-app-region` set to `drag`.

```css
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F0D6BA;
    -webkit-user-region: drag;
}

.drag:hover {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #7EA5A3;
}
```

It works perfectly in the browser, but if I use it in Electron, nothing changes when I hover my mouse over element.

Comment: check out this thread: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8730

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand why this happens now: Any elements with `-webkit-app-region: drag` do not receive mouse events. Thanks [41 72 6c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758017/41-72-6c)!

Answer (score 5):

hey a bit late but you can add `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` on the element/component that you need to detect mouse events on hope this helps.